# JSON web token - applying different user roles to different routes

Tags: json, authentication, json-web-token

What is the standard practice for using JWTs in authentication mechanisms which require roles?

- Should roles be contained somewhere within the predefined public claim names?

  - `['iss', 'sub', 'aud', 'exp', 'nbf', 'iat', 'jti]`
- ... Or should an application specific private claim name be used?
- Or should the application refrain from putting roles in JWTs and keep all role based logic within the application only?

---

More detail:

When using JSON web tokens as a user authentication mechanism, and you apply the authentication on a set of routes, when a token is valid, authentication is valid for all routes in the set. If the token is not valid, it is invalid for all routes in the set.

This is great if all users have the same level of access. However, if users have different roles, say "user" and "admin", and only the "admin"s have access to certain routes, this falls down.

Comment: I wonder if it's a bad idea to specify the allowed permissions inside a JWT public claim. JWT are not meant to be tampered with after creation right ? Suppose a user signs up as a normal user and we have a "role" public claim as "role: user", now few months later, if we want to allow this user to be a moderator, we can't modify the JWT public claim right ? Should roles be tied to the database User entity ? That way, the JWT only needs to act as the authentication token. What the user can do is up to the server's database. That's what OAuth does right (OAuth is not an authentication protocol) ?

Comment: @Zhang Yup, I do have concerns about precisely those sorts of issues. Given that once issued, a token cannot be revoked, that does indicate thjat even when roles (or any other claims) are specified in the JWT, they must still be verified each time a request is made - based on what you say. In any case, that is why I have asked this question - I would like to know what the standard practice is for JWTs.

Comment: I was playing around with JWT myself the other day. I think I'll leave the token solely as an authorization token but let the server handle roles and permissioning. Feels more natural to me that way as the server could have an admin panel where admin logs in and tick a checkbox to update a user's role to moderator etc. I used Sailsjs (http://sailsjs.org/) and we have something called policy, some sort of middleware thing runs before the route reaches a controller. I have a policy called "isAdmin.js" which is applied to all the AdminController's actions (MVC framework).

Comment: @Zhang Yeah, I am, beginning to think - from the lack of responses - that there is no "standard" thing to do here. Thanks for the info on how you're using it!